# Removed Time from Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I wrote the following query. This query returns two fields.  Firstly, it returns an integer that represents a date, and it then converts that integer into a date.

```
select DISTINCT date_column,     
cast(convert(varchar(10), date_column) as date) as [Week Label]     
from table_one    
order by date_column desc;
```

The conversion works well.  However, the date that is returned contains a time.  How can I get rid of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this to remove time part

```
convert(date, getdate())
```

OR

you can use this also

```
convert(varchar(10), getdate(),120)
```

Comment: Also, if they have any servers running 2005 or older, the first option will not work but the second will.  Says he's running 2008 but thought i would just add that.

Comment: Does CAST always include the time part?

Comment: It is not necessary that cast always returns the timepart Please Refer this for detailed info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: If you want to get more details on case & convert then I will suggest to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GHUfb5k-a8

Answer (score 0):

`convert(varchar(10), getdate(),101)` doesn't have a time part, just the date.

I used http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp for the options but this one from MSDN may be better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx